# Is it possible to solve this ODE by separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $ydx +3xdy =14y^4dy$. Is there a clever trick which would allow to solve this equation by the method of separation of variables?

Comment: Any chance that second $dy$ should actually be a $dx$? In that case, it's a Bernoulli type equation and a substitution will make it soluble.

Comment: No, this form should be correct.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution, try an integrating factor of the form $I(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separable equations are exact, 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)g(y)\implies g(y)dy-f(x)dx=0
$$
This one is not since
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} y=1\ne \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(
3x-14y^4)=3
$$

Answer (score 3):

No it's not seperable in y
$$ydx +3xdy =14y^4dy$$
$$y +3xy' =14y^4y'$$
$$yx'+3x=14y^4$$
it's a classical equation thats easy to solve

First solve the homogeneous equation
$$yx'+3x=0 \implies \ln|x|=-3\ln|y|+K \implies x=\frac K {y^3}$$
Now plug K in the non homogeneous equation and consider K as $K(y)$ Solve the first order ( separable equation) to find K
$$y(K'y^{-3}-3Ky^{-4})+3Ky^ {-3}=14y^4 $$
Then you get a seperable equation in $K(y)$
$$K'=14y^6$$
Integrate
$$\int dK=14\int y^6dy$$
$$\implies K( y)=2y^7+C$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{x(y)=\frac K {y^3}=2y^4+\frac {C} {y^3}}$$

Comment: Can you please clarify your method? It appears you are first finding the homogeneous solution, where $K$ also depends on $y$, and then you substitute it into the original equations. This is an interesting method, I've never seen it before. So, basically, $K$ is constant only for the homogeneous case, but then we can find $K$ if the equation is made non-homogeneous.

Comment: @sequence its a classical method that is used for 2linear diff equation...as you have observed first step solve the homgeneous equation...then consider the K constant as a function of the variable here its y so $K=K(y)$ and plug in the non homogeneous equation then solve for K ...it's seperable

Comment: @sequence I added some lines I hope it's more clear now

Comment: @sequence I think this is called variation of parameters

Answer (score 2):

This equation $$ydx +3xdy =14y^4dy$$ is not separable.

Note that if you try to factor $dy$, you will get an expression involving both $x$ and $y.$

$$ydx=(14y^4-3x)dy$$

We can solve the equation if we solve for $x$ as a function of $y.$

Note that  $$dx/dy=(14y^3-3x/y)$$ Which is linear.

Comment: What method would one use to solve it?

Comment: Try  to solve x as a function of y. find dx/dy and go from there. you will find a linear equation to solve.